# How to enter text into the "Write something..." box on Facebook and click Submit

Tags: javascript, facebook, safari

I am trying to manipulate Facebook pages in various ways, using Javascript browser elements. I'd need to be able to insert some text into the top "Type something..." box that shows on my site's fan page (or alternately, "click into" the field and I can type the text using GUI scripting), then click the "submit" button as if i'd done it by hand. It's tricky since the page is very Ajax heavy and I can't find the names of the elements I need to manipulate, let alone how to manipulate them as they're not using traditional form fields I'm used to. Can anyone help me figure out how to do this with javascript commands, which I'd be calling from Applescript on the Mac?

Many thanks in advance.

UPDATE

Thanks for the comments below. Believe me, I am not trying to do anything spammy or douchy, mainly posting links to products that have gone live on page facebook page, but do it during the business day when people are on rather than at strange hours of the day. I am located in Japan so my sleep period is right when people are using FB.

The solution I came up with for clicking the button was got using UI Browser, an outstanding tool if you're trying to script on the Mac. The script that clicked the button for me was:

tell application "Safari"
    activate
    set thename to name of (get current tab of window 1)
    delay 3
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Safari"
            try
                click button "Share" of group 1 of group 2 of list 3 of group 9 of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of group 3 of window thename -- this one works on the mini?
            on error
                click button "Share" of group 1 of group 2 of list 3 of group 9 of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of group 2 of window thename -- did not work
            end try
        end tell
    end tell
end tell

Hope this is useful to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. But even if you could you want to post comments on peoples behalf and expect them to continue using your site...

It would be [cross site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) - and since the comment box is in an iFrame it actually exists on Facebook's site and not your site.

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating web pages for functionality is rarely a good idea, since you can introduce bugs and security flaws.

In this instance, if all you want to do is post a status, just use the [Facebook API](http://developers.facebook.com/) thats what its there for. They provide libraries (I think, at the very least they are available) to make it easy to use whatever language you want.

From a UX PoV, people don't like being forced to post things, so if this is just for your use, then fine, otherwise, make sure that people know whats going on. Its only polite.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I know auto-posting has the potnetial for douchiness, and that's not my intention. Mainly, I use Twitter and post product updates to my customers who want to read them, and because I live in Japan I have to schedule the tweets to keep them all from being when people aren't online. Since Facebook treats company/fan sites differently, there's no way to have any of this show up on my company page, hence the need for something that simulates me doing it myself. These are updates that people actually want ^_^